# suggest a tool similar to tcpview

Tags: monitoring, connection, windows

Can anyone suggest a tool for Windows similar to Sysinternals' `tcpview` which monitor current all connections and also counts and shows traffic/speed?

Comment: What are you looking to do that `tcpview` isn't doing?

Comment: It does everything besides traffic counting. That's what I need most (per connection). I don't need historical data, just current connections (assumed that they initiated after `tcpview` has started)

Comment: If you want aggregate traffic and bandwidth monitoring, that's way beyond the scope of TCPView, which was meant to be a GUI replacement for netstat. There are plenty of monitoring tools out there, but I don't know of any that let you drill down to individual connections. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with netmon but you'd probably have to script a count connection parser.  Do you need the number of connections or the traffic?  If you just want the number of connections you can get that from perfmon \tcpv4\connections established and tcpv6\connections established for bandwith used the formula is (((Bytes total\Sec * 8)/current bandwidth) * 100)

Comment: I guess `perfmon` is a closest to what I'd like to get though not that flexible and light

Comment: @dada not flexible I can almost see (because you can write scripts) but not light? It has 0 footprint if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark and CurrPorts (NirSoft)

Comment: Wireshark will allow you to isolate a conversation and measure the aggregate data and bandwidth for just that conversation. But it doesn't integrate directly with TCPView or CurrPorts.

Comment: I've quick check `currports` but it seems like another version of `tcpview` - just current connections (though can monitor UDP). But can't see if it can count traffic. `Wireshark` come a bit heavy on resources - it is not just a simple monitoring tool. Perhaps, tool I'm looking really do not exist.

Comment: Personally I would use Wireshark or the other 2 mentioned here, but I have tried using Networx and TCPEye when I was testing similar tools. They just did not cut it. You might as well try them.